# Doubly Linked-List, Linked-lists and dynamic arrays in C++

Tags: c++, list, vector, stl

I'm new to C++ and probably these questions are so simple and basic [and sorry for that!]. Here I have two basic questions:

1. As I understand vectors in C++ are dynamic arrays. They can change size by pushing back/front elements into them.

   My question is: Are vectors allocated dynamically or the "dynamic array" name is just called because of the changing size capability?
   dynamically allocated array and dynamic arrays make me completely
   confused!
2. STL lists are linked-lists in C++ (again, as I understand). Are these doubly-linked lists or singly-linked list?

Thanks,

Comment: A good reference for [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) and [`std::forward_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list) might be useful.

Comment: 1. Typically a `vector` is statically allocated but contains a dynamically allocated array. The methods of the `vector` manage this dynamic array for you resizing and freeing the dynamic array as required. You can dynamically allocate the `vector`, but this defeats the point; you now have to manually manage the memory of a data structure designed to manage memory for you.
2. A `list` is probably allocated as a doubly linked list, but this is not required.

Answer (score 0):

Vectors are allocated dynamically, as you can see in the mentioned [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back). You can see this better in `push_back` function:

> If the new size() is greater than capacity() then all iterators and references (including the past-the-end iterator) are invalidated. Otherwise only the past-the-end iterator is invalidated.

Also, stick this in your mind which its complexity is amortized constant (as an instance, you can see [this](https://www.interviewcake.com/concept/java/dynamic-array-amortized-analysis)).

For more info (mentioned in comments), you can find the real list as `forward_list`:

> It is implemented as a singly-linked list and essentially does not have any overhead compared to its implementation in C. Compared to std::list this container provides more space efficient storage when bidirectional iteration is not needed.

Also, as mentioned in the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/), list is implemented as a doubly linked list.

> List containers are implemented as **doubly-linked lists**; Doubly linked lists can store each of the elements they contain in different and unrelated storage locations. The ordering is kept internally by the association to each element of a link to the element preceding it and a link to the element following it.

Comment: You may want to mention that [std::forward_list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list) exists if one desires a singly linked list.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Are vectors allocated dynamically or the "dynamic array" name is just called because of the changing size capability?

As far as I know, vectors are called dynamic arrays because their size can change at run time. But indeed, they allocate the array dynamically.

> 2. STL lists are linked-lists in C++ (again, as I understand). Are these doubly-linked lists or singly-linked list?

Both. `list` is doubly linked, and `slist` is singly linked. The name `std::forward_list` was used in stead of `slist` when the singly linked list was introduced to the standard library (with minor differences to the STL version).